# SQL anexar una columna a una consulta con los siguiente (son fechas ): si fechaini1>= fechaini409 poner 'ok'(en la columna nueva) sino, poner 'mal'

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

[image: .]

debo anexar una nueva columna en una consulta previa con los siguiente (son fechas ): si fechaini_min>= fechaini409 poner 'ok'(en la columna nueva) sino, poner 'revisar'

Comment: Bienvenida Julián H, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas. En este caso podrías agregar una muestra de tus datos como texto y algo del código con el que estas intentando resolver el problema

Comment: Hola julian podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
FechaIni_Vmin, 
FechaIni_B409, 
case
    when FechaIni_Vmin >= FechaIni_B409 THEN 'OK'
    else 'Revisar'
end as Detalles
from tabla
```

En la **claúsula select** se utiliza el **condicional case when**, donde se comprueba si **FechaIni_Vmin** es mayor que **FechaIni_B409**, en caso de serlo se proyecta una nueva columna  con el valor **'OK'**, en caso contrario el valor de la columna proyectada sera **'Revisar'**, a esta nueva columna se le da como alias el nombre de **Detalles**.